# How to replace an array in perl with a query for contents of a sql database?

Tags: html, mysql, database, perl, dbi

Edit: (See Revised Code Near bottom) I have the code working to pull from the 2 databases (I know some cleaning is still needed),
but where I am stuck is, I was prviously able to use:

```
next unless $currentuser ~~ @las;
```

but once I linked the mySQL database, it isn't filtering out undefined/unqualified (blank) results. I am not sure how to restructure this function to re-enable the functionality. (I think the way I am approaching the logic may be off). But this is where I am currently confused and need guidance.

---

I currently use this code to view logged in users to check for employees in our department:

```
 #! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} ="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
use DBI;
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();

#current emplyees go here:
my @las = qw( 

user12
user13
user14
user15
user16
user17
user18
user19
user20
user21
user22
user23
user24
user25
user26
user27
user28
user29
user30
user31
user32
user33
user34
user35
user36
user37
user38
user39
user40
user41
user42
user43
user44
user45
user46
user47
user48
user49
user50
user51
user52
user53
user54
user55
user56
user57
user58
user59
user60
user61
user62
user63
user64
user65
user66
user67
user68
user69
user70
user71
user72
user73
user74
user75
user76
user77
user78
user79
user80
user81
user82
user83
user84
user85
user86
user87
user88
user89
user90
user91
user92
user93
user94
user95
user96
user97
user98
user99
user100
user101
user102
user103
user104
user105
user106
user107
user108
user109
user110
user111
user112
user113
user114
user115
user116
user117
user118
user119
user120
user121
user122
user123
user124
user125
user126
user127
user128
user129
user130
user131
user132
user133
user134
user135
user136
user137
user138
user139
user140
user141
user142
user143
user144
user145
user146
user147
user148
user149
user150
user151
user152
user153
user154
user155
user156
user157
user158
user159
user160
user161
user162
user163
user164
user165
user166
user167
user168
user169
user170
user171
user172
user173
user174
user175
user176
user177
user178
user179
user180
user181
user182
user183
user184
user185
user186
user187
user188
user189
user190
user191
user192
user193
user194
user195
user196
user197
user198
user199
user200
user201
user202
user203
user204
user205
user206
user207
user208
user209
user210
user211
user212
user213
user214
user215
user216
user217
user218
user219
user220
user221
user222
user223
user224
user225
user226
user227
user228
user229
user230
user231
user232
user233
user234
user235
user236
user237
user238
user239
user240
user241
user242
user243
user244
user245
user246
user247
user248
user249
user250
user251
user252
user253
user254
user255
user256
user257
user258
user259
user260
user261
user262
user263
user264
user265
user266
user267
user268
user269
user270
user271
user272
user273
user274
user275
user276
user277

systemdefault
admin1
admin2
admin3


);

#Find Current Users
$login="logg";
$password="pass32";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Oracle:icsprod",$login,$password);
die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n" unless (defined $dbh);

# Search Zone 2

my $sql = qq{ 
SELECT  hosts.currentuser, TO_CHAR(hosts.lastlogin, 'HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY'),
        hosts.host_name
FROM    infadmin.inv_hosts hosts
WHERE  (hosts.host_name = '1408bcc204ap1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p3')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p4')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135m1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p3')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p4')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p5')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p6')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p7')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p8')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p9')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p10')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p10')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p10')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb10p10')



ORDER BY hosts.host_name
};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my($currentuser, $lastlogin, $host_name);
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$currentuser, \$lastlogin, \$host_name);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=300>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>\n";
print "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
print "body { font-family: \"Arial\", sans-serif; font-size: small; color: black }\n";
print "</style>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<title>\n";
print "Staff Stations\n";
print "</title>\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<table>\n";
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
print "<tr><td><u>Zone 2</u></td><td><u>Login</u></td></tr>\n";
while($sth->fetch()) {
        next unless $currentuser~~@las  ;
        $lastlogin=~s/ .*$//;
        $host_name=~s/1408//;
        foreach(@las)   {
                if ($currentuser eq "$_") {
                       $lacolor = "orange";
                        last;
                } else {
                        $lacolor = "black";
                }
        }
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$host_name</td>";
        print "<td><font color=\"$lacolor\">$currentuser</font></td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
$sth->finish();

print "</table>";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";

$sth->finish();$sth->finish();

#end code

$
b
->disconnect();
```

The usernames are already stored in a mysql database, I am trying to add lines to connect to it as follows, but I am stuck as to how to continue:

```
#Read Employee database


my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:myadmpr01", "user", "pass64");
die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n" unless (defined $dbh);

my $sql = qq{ 
SELECT  user_id, 
FROM    lsoemployee_info

};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

I am trying to compare the `icsprod`against the `myadmpr01` for usernames so that out hr department can maintain this easily as they update the `myadmpr01` database for current/non-current employees. `icsprod` is updated continuously and simply defines the current user. We would also like to return the user's fullname, rather than continuously look up usernames. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Revised code:

```
  #! /usr/bin/perl
$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} ="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
use DBI;

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:lsopskeys:myadmpr01.itap.purdue.edu", "lsops", "Fl4sh_l1ght")
  or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sql = qq{ 
  SELECT  user_id, 
  FROM    lsoemployee_data
};

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

my @las = map { $_->[0] } $sth->fetchall_arrayref;

$login="user";
$password="pass";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Oracle:icsprod",$login,$password);
die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n" unless (defined $dbh);

# Zone 2 ROWS CODE
my $sql = qq{ 
SELECT  hosts.currentuser, TO_CHAR(hosts.lastlogin, 'HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY'),
        hosts.host_name
FROM    infadmin.inv_hosts hosts
WHERE   (hosts.host_name = '1408stew102p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew102p2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew102p3')

OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p3')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p4')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p5')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p6')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p7')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p8')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p9')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p10')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408stew111p11')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathb18p5')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p3')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mathg135p4')

OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408heav227m1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408heav227m2')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408heav227m3')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408mthw116p1')
OR      (hosts.host_name = '1408hamp3144p21')

ORDER BY hosts.host_name
};

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my($currentuser, $lastlogin, $host_name);
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$currentuser, \$lastlogin, \$host_name);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=300>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>\n";
print "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
print "body { font-family: \"Arial\", sans-serif; font-size: small; color: black }\n";
print "</style>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<title>\n";
print "LA station usage.\n";
print "</title>\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<table>\n";
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
print "<tr><td><font color=\"DodgerBlue \"><u>Zone 2 Station</u></td><td><font color=\"DodgerBlue \"><u>Login</u></td></tr>\n";
while($sth->fetch()) {
      #next unless $currentuser ~~ @las;
       $lastlogin=~s/ .*$//;
        $host_name=~s/1408//;
        foreach(@las)   {
                if ($currentuser eq "$_") {
                       $lacolor = "orange";
                        last;
                } else {
                        $lacolor = "black";
                }
        }
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$host_name</td>";
        print "<td><font color=\"$lacolor\">$currentuser</font></td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
$sth->finish();
print "</table>";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
$sth->finish();$sth->finish();

#end code
$
b
->disconnect();
```

Comment: Please always use `use strict;` as well as `use warnings;`.

Comment: What is the best way to validate perl code?

Comment: `perl -c script.pl` will verify that it can be compiled. Having the pragmas I mentioned in the previous comment is the best way to ensure things are legit while coding.

Comment: I see you've corrected `$las` to `@las` in the `map` line,  but you missed the use of `$las` in the `print()` on the following line. And why is `$b->disconnect()` spread over three lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to populate `@las` from the database, then you want something like this:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:myadmpr01', 'user', 'pass64')
  or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sql = qq{ 
  SELECT  user_id, 
  FROM    lsoemployee_info
};

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

my @las = map { $_->[0] } $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
```

**Update:** I wrote that last line of code as I would write it for a client. I always assume that my code will be read and maintained by people who know Perl. If you have doubts about the abilities of your programmers, you might be better advised to write something like that:

```
my @las;

foreach ($sth->fetchall_arrayref) {
  push @las, $_->[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to implement this with the existing code. Also wouldn't it be ("DBI:mysql:myadmpr01", "user", "pass64")?

Comment: I just took your code and added a single line after it. I'm not sure what part is confusing you. Also, I changed the double quotes to single quotes as you only need double quotes for variable interpolation and escape sequences like `\n` or `\t`.

Comment: gotcha, i'm giving it a go, looks like I was combining 2 different sections. I may have to ask the people maintaining the database if the names for SELECT are right

Comment: "I seem to be doing something wrong" isn't very helpful. What makes you think that? What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? To be honest, I think the biggest mistake you are making is to just ignore all the good advice you have been given over the last few questions that you have asked. Why haven't you added `strict` and `warnings`? Why aren't you using CSS? Why are you using multiple `print` statements instead of templates? Why are you trying to set `$las` when my code used `@las`?

Comment: sorry, more specifically, I wonder if my DBI is correct:

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:lsopskeys:myadmpr01.itap.purdue.edu", "user", "passcode")

Comment: is myadmpr01.itap.purdue.edu correct way to do host? I've also seen some formats where 'port' is used as part of the argument. Not sure if this ins needed here...

Comment: @JozefPietrzak: I have three things to say to you. Firstly, the questions you are now asking have little to do with your original question. Perhaps you should ask a new question. Secondly, if you have questions about the syntax to use for DBI, then I good start might be the [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) (or [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle)) documentation. Finally, if you don't start to use (or, at least, acknowledge) the good help you're getting, then people might stop taking the time to help you.

Comment: I think i'm having trouble understanding how '{ $_->[0] }' functions in 'my @las = map { $_->[0] } $sth->fetchall_arrayref;' The ->[0] would seem to indicate number values, but these will be strings

Comment: Here is the [documentation for `map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). `map` is a mechanism for transforming lists. You pass it a block of code (in this case `{ $_->[0] }`) and a list (in this case the return value from `$sth->fetchall_arrayref`). Each element of the list, in turn, is assigned to `$_` and the block of code is executed. Whatever the the block of code returns is added to the transformed list. The `$_->[0]` is looking up the first element in an array reference that's held in `$_`. Nothing about that code indicates that we are dealing with numbers.

Comment: @JozefPietrzak: You seem very confused. I really think it's worth your time to spend a few days working through *Learning Perl* and *Intermediate Perl*. That will save you a lot of time.

Comment: I FINALLY got it... My sql database was spitting out references instead of readable strings. That's why the results wouldn't compare. I ended up needing to do `next unless $currentuser~~@{las};` then they actually compared! :)

Comment: I really did appreciate your and everyone else's input greatly. I'm sorry if that come accross

Comment: You ended up needing to do... nothing? It's not your database that is returning references. Your database knows nothing at all about references. It was DBI or DBD::mysql that was creating references (because that's the only way to create complex data structures in Perl).

Comment: No. DBI wasn't misreading it. DBI was doing exactly what it is supposed to to. As I said in my last comment, using references is the only way to create complex data structures of the kind that DBI methods need to return. The only error here was you misreading (or, perhaps, not reading) the documentation.

Comment: And I don't know what you think that `$currentuser ~~ @{las}` is doing. The braces are completely superfluous and using the smartmatch operator (`~~`) is a terrible idea as it is currently marked as "experimental" and is likely to be removed or have its behaviour changed greatly in future versions of Perl.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seemed stable enough, it was recommended by a friend. I seriously doubt we will be changing our perl version on our server anytime soon. I am open to better ways to write the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query is a union of two subqueries, but one subquery has one column in its result and the other has two columns. This is not allowed in a UNION. All subqueries must have the same number of columns, and compatible data types in all columns. This has nothing to do with Perl, it's just a requirement of the SQL language.

In Perl, you should have called the query in a way that allowed you to see the SQL error it caused.

```
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->err)
{
  die "ERROR! return code: . $sth->err . " error msg: " . $sth->errstr . "\n";
}
```

DBI also has connection options to make any SQL error cause the calling script to die, or print the error. See http://www.perlhowto.com/dbi_handling_database_errors

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 });
```

Comment: ok, sorry. I fixed it to just focus on getting the username for right now.